I can't connect ASP.NET Web API with .NET Maui

I want to connect my first maui test app with ASP.NET Web API that retrieves data from mongoDB. When the ASP.NET Web API is running, I can easily retrieve my data from Swagger UI, but when it comes to retrieving data in my MAUI app, I get an error

Connection Failure

Could you explain me why is this happening and what I should do about it?
Here is my code from MAUI app:
private async void OnSubmitClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pesel = peselEntry.Text;

    try
    {
        var response = await App.HttpClient.GetAsync($"https://localhost:7183/api/Patients/Test");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var patient = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Patients>();
            await DisplayAlert("Oto dane", $"Imię: {patient.Name}, Nazwisko: {patient.Surname}", "OK");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Błąd", "Pacjent nie znaleziony.", "OK");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Błąd", $"Wystąpił problem: {ex.Message}", "OK");
    }
}

I just added CORS to program.cs in ASP.NET, but it didn't help

use the IP or FQDN of your server, not localhost

Doesn't work either

Then you have a network issue.  Is your local server setup to handle remote requests?

I honestly don't know. What I do know is that when I created the Windows Forms app, it pulled data from an API that connected to the postgresql database without any issues. How can I configure these requests?

it depends on what server you're using, but its well documented.  You can test using the browser on your mobile device (or emulator) to confirm that it can connect to the swagger endpoint

After pasting this url my mobile phone refused to connect - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

That is a pretty clear sign that your server is not setup to handle remote requests.

So i should change configuration in IIS Servers files? Honestly I don't understand such things and would prefer not to crash something in these files. I tried the IP address to try to connect but it didn't work

Yes, that's what you need to do.  If you are using IIS express (or whatever they call it these days) then it will not handle requests from remote devices by default.  And your mobile app is seen as a remote device, even if it is running on an emulator on the same machine.

Could you please post the full error log about this problem?

A WinForms app runs on your local machine, so can access a localhost site. A Maui app runs (usually) in an emulator, which is a different machine.
As IISExpress can only serve to localhost, you need to setup your site to run under IIS. You can still debug from there!
The Maui app then needs to call that site by machine name or IP address.
